# Right way to poll a server even when app get destroyed

Tags: android

I need you to tell me what would be the correct way to handle the following situation:

I am making an application that has to pul a server to register.
This thread has to remain active even if the application is destroyed.
Through the server I get SIP calls, which I want to generate notifications to accept or reject.
Also make P2P calls from the application. 
The subject of the calls is solved with PJSIP, call and receive, as well as the connection with the server.
I need to know with which to handle the service that puts all this together.
I try with AsyncTask, Service and tryService but I can not get the service live when the app dies.
Thank you very much to all!

Comment: When you say "app is killed" are you force stopping it, or just closing the activity through the task manager?

Comment: close the activity through the task manage

Comment: Using a service or intentservice is how you want to poll the server when the activity has been destroyed.  You may also want to look into Volley.

Comment: @Pablo Baxter if the app is launched again i need to connect it to the same Service is this posible?

Comment: From the sound of it, you are looking to use a bound service.  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html